# How to convert from netcdf4 format back to netcdf/netcdf3? Ocean Current files

Tags: netcdf, file-conversion, netcdf4

My company is using RPS Oilmap software to accurately model, simulate, and mitigate the impact of oil spills on marine and coastal environments. This software reads from current and wind data files in order to use particle tracking algorithms to determine the direction of travel of the oil. We obtain these data files externally through various metocean data sites.

Copernicus EU MetOcean data centre has recently updated it's file format to ARCO (netcdf4) - but unfortunately, Oilmap only reads current files in netcdf3 format, and does not fully process netcdf4 format - it isn't reading the timestamps on the current files correctly resulting in the file not being usable.

Is there a way to convert a netcdf4 file with ocean current data (u and v value, latitude, longitude, date and time variables), back to a netcdf3 file?

Other data sources are available, but they are not as reliable - Copernicus is our primary source for ocean current data, and we require a degree of resilience to operate effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Typically this can be solved by NCO or CDO. Try the following:

```
ncks -3 in.nc out.nc
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Robert says above, both NCO and CDO will work. If the input file has variables larger than ~2 GB, then you must specify a format capacious enough to hold such data:

```
   ncks -3 in.nc out.nc # Up to 2 GB
   ncks -6 in.nc out.nc # Up to 4 GB
   ncks -5 in.nc out.nc # No limit on variable size
```